# Can't run Appium programatically on Apple M1 with Java via Jenkins

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, appium, apple-m1

This is what I got when trying to run tests:
`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "appium": error=2, No such file or directory`

`appium -v` from Jenkins job shows current version, so it CAN see Appium;

Connecting from another mac via SSH and running tests with the same command works fine as well

Looks like the issue is in Jenkins master.

Slave is connected via SSH.

Master is running Linux, but I don’t have an access to it, yet.

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My guess is that Jenkins is installed on Mac OS X on a jenkins user account and not the local account where Appium is installed. Jenkins cannot access programs from another user on Mac. Do you login on SSH with the jenkins user or the local user account? My solution was to have Appium Desktop running on the Mac, then the Jenkins job was able to access the localhost Appium server.

Comment: I log in with local user account via SSH.
Yes, that is what I've done (as a workaround), started appium in the Terminal and left it running.
Thanks for your reply.